# SPFx development without internet

Tags: spfx

My Organization does not allow https://github.com , so the command :
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
is failing to create a webpart project.

Any option to create webpart without github for SharePoint framework extensions ?

[image]
My proxy blocks all github URLs, so even this command fails :
npm config set proxy

Answer (score 0):

You can download the binary file from elsewhere, and set `SASS_BINARY_PATH` to the absolute path to the file. Then `npm install` should be able to get the file from the local path instead of download it from the GitHub.

Comment: You can also use Yarn.